# How to handle wpf datagrid MouseMove event in viewmodel...in MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, events, viewmodel, mousemove

HI,

I have a wpf-datagrid in view, i am following mvvm model...so no code in "codebehind".
I wud like to handle "mousemove" event in viewmodel..how do i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this in the *code behind*! The *MVVM*-pattern doesn't prohibit some code in the *code behind*.
The question is what are you going to handle in the *MouseMove* event? Is it something view specific? If so, you can handle it in the *code behind*, which is a part of the view.
Or are you going to handle something that will inkvoke some action in the business objects? If so, consider to invoke a `ICommand` command.

Comment: The question is about to make the handling of MouseMove Event in the Viewmodel.